# I can't send forum data with httpclient in json format

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send forum data in json format for a website, but I'm getting an error. I am showing the error in the photo I will be glad if you help.

My Code

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        StringContent content = new StringContent("{\"email\":\"babaprogang1@gmail.com\"," + "\"password\":\"123123asdasd\"," + "\"genderId\":\""+0+"\"," + "\"marketingEmailsAuthorized\":true," + "\"conditionOfMembershipApproved\":true," + "\"protectionOfPersonalDataApproved\":true" + "\"}");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");


        var gord = await client.PostAsync("https://auth.trendyol.com/signup",content);
```

the data i need to send to the website

```
{
"email": "babalangfgo@gmail.com",
"password": "123asdasd",
"genderId": 0,
"marketingEmailsAuthorized": true,
"conditionOfMembershipApproved": true,
"protectionOfPersonalDataApproved": true
}
```

the error i encountered

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRh5i.jpg)

I have to send like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87ohb.jpg)

Comment: You may want to consider using NuGet package "Newtonsoft.JSON". As for your current code, you may have to escape the curly-brace by using a second one. Instead of `{` try using `{{` and instead of `}` try using `}}`.

Comment: can you send me how i can do it in code

Comment: Newtonsoft.json has lots of examples available online. Hundreds, both in their official documentation and elsewhere. Do some basic research. Try something, and come back to us with your attempt if you still get stuck. Building JSON by hand as you are doing now is a great way for silly mistakes to happen. Always build a c# object and then serialise it with a reliable library such as newtonsoft

Comment: All of that breaking up of the JSON string you're building seems like a breeding ground for syntax problems.  Why not make that whole thing one string that can be more easily read?  (Failing the use of JSON serialization of an actual object instead of course.)  Writing code that's easily read by humans makes it much easier for you, as a human, to spot problems in that code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**Add NuGet package**: Newtonsoft.Json

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse**
- Search: **Newtonsoft.Json**
- Click **Install**
- If prompted, click **OK**

**Add class**: Class1

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: Class1.cs)

**Class1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NewtonsoftTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public int genderId { get; set; }
        public bool marketingEmailsAuthorized { get; set; }
        public bool conditionOfMembershipApproved { get; set; }
        public bool protectionOfPersonalDataApproved { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();
myClass1.email = "your_email_address";
myClass1.password = "your_password";
myClass1.genderId = 0;
myClass1.marketingEmailsAuthorized = true;
myClass1.conditionOfMembershipApproved = true;
myClass1.protectionOfPersonalDataApproved = true;

//serialize
string jsonStr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass1, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonStr);

StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonStr);

                   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "\ from the tail of your string:

```
 StringContent content = new StringContent("{\"email\":\"babaprogang1@gmail.com\"," + "\"password\":\"123123asdasd\"," + "\"genderId\":\""+0+"\"," + "\"marketingEmailsAuthorized\":true," + "\"conditionOfMembershipApproved\":true," + 
"\"protectionOfPersonalDataApproved\":true}");
```